# Use webpack alias in custom loader

Tags: webpack, loader

I've created a custom webpack loader that needs to load additional files within. Everything is workin fine until url to that additional file hasn't got alias eg. @utils.
Is there a way to resolve that url with some kind of service or helper from webpack?